# Validation only firing on submit for additional methods

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

By default, jQuery Validate validates on keyup and blur. This does not work for custom validations added with `addMethod`, including all of those in the included additional-methods.js script.

[Example plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/hiPAzOg37PB2qmY3PPrb?p=preview)

In the above example email will validate on keyup but phone (`phoneUS`) will only validate on submit.

How can I make additional methods work exactly like built-in methods?

Comment: Your premise and/or Plunker is flawed.  Enter `ab` into first box and click away:  http://jsfiddle.net/op2x7f85/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make additional methods work exactly like built-in methods?

They already do.

The problem is within your Plunker:

```
<input type="phoneUS" name="phone">
```

You have not properly defined the `phoneUS` rule anyplace, because `type="phoneUS"` is not a valid element `type`.

You *could* use `type`, `class`, or an HTML5 validation attribute to define the jQuery Validate rules inline.  However in this case, since there is no such `type` or HTML5 attribute named `"phoneUS"`, only `class` will properly work inline...

```
<input type="text" class="phoneUS" name="phone">
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/w145puuz/**

Comment: You're completely correct. Out of curiosity where is this documented?

Comment: @TrueWill, [*"Can be combined with class/attribute/data rules."*](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#rules) and see the [Tag Wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).